# Factors numeric output when i set string input

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I'm working in a shiny app and I need make a factor with database values.
In all examples people do something like this:

```
  selectInput("selectSectorAgrupado","Sector agrupado",
               c("Cylinders" = "cyl",
              "Transmission" = "am",
              "Gears" = "gear"),selected=NULL,multiple = FALSE)
```

In this case the user see "Cylinders" string but the value is "cyl". I need do this but the factor values isn't strings, they are data frames fields from database. I try to do something similar but when i put a text field in factor he return numbers.
Using this:

```
sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE
```

The console returns this:

> [1] Actividades recreativas Agencias de viaje        [3] Alimentación
>   Bazares                  [5] Comercio electrónico    Gremios, vivienda
>   [7] Electrodomésticos, SAT  Energia                  [9] Enseñanza
>   Grandes Superficies     [11] Hosteleria              Informática
>   [13] Joyeria, Relojeria      Muebles                 [15] Otro
>   comercio por menor Otros                   [17] Publicidad
>   Seguros                 [19] Servicios bancarios     Telefonía
>   [21] Textil, Calzado         Tintorerias             [23] Transportes 
>   Venta domiciliaria      [25] Automóviles             Promoción
>   inmobiliaria

But when I put the code into a factor:

```
c(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE)
```

He return this

> [1]  1  2  3  5  6 11  7  8  9 10 12 13 14 15 16 17 19 20 21 22
>   [21] 23 24 25 26  4 18

I'm new in R programing and maybe i don't understand good factors, but i need some help.
Thank you

### EDITED (More problems)

OK, the solution for the first problem is solved. The solution is save in factor the values as character like this:

```
c(as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE))
```

But the problem continues. When i asociate string with value R return a error.
The code:

```
c(as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE)=as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0CODIGO))
```

Return the error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in "c(as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE)="

Comment: factors are internally stored as integers, that is what you see when you do `c()` (didn't know about that, by the way ;-) . Try `as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE)`

Comment: @apom, you can check edit? I have more problems, thank you;)

Comment: It's not clear about the data structure you want, but since you're new to R, I'll guess it is a "named vector". Try `setNames(object = as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0CODIGO), nm = as.character(sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE))` . By the way, you don't need the `c()` around your vectors (unless you're trying to combine values, which is not the case here).

Comment: Though I don't recommend that, if the values in `sectorAgrupado$L0NOMBRE` are not unique (not the case in your example, but with your actual data?), since it will give you a vector with non unique names, which is plain wrong. Maybe giv more thought to the desired data structure?

Comment: @apom  i have for this, 2 tables from database, first table have LOCODIGO as primary key and LONOMBRE as a name string. The second table have SECODIGO as primary key, SENOMBRE as a name string and SECOLO as foreign key relation with the first table. I need get from a inputSelect the names from the first table and with the name get the primary key and make a query with the second table

Comment: Finally i do it. With :  `sector <- sector[which(sector$SENOMBRE == input$selectSector), ]` in ui.R and `sectorAgrupado <- sectorAgrupado[which(sectorAgrupado$L0CODIGO == input$selectSectorAgrupado), ]` in server.R